# How to use unwind Mongo Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have an Application list with an embedded versions array. I need to use aggregate framework to unwind the embedded part to show all versions in a list, but when I run this code the output is empty.

```golang
package model

import "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

type ApplicationVersion struct {
    ID            bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ApplicationID bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name          string
    Version       string
    Status        int
    ReleaseDate   string
}

func App() {
    Apps := []model.ApplicationVersion{}

    if err := productsCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {
            "$unwind": "$versions",
        },
        {
            "$project": bson.M{
                "_id":           "$versions._id",
                "applicationid": "$_id",
                "name":          "$name",
                "version":       "$versions.versionnumber",
                "status":        "$versions.status",
                "releasedate":   "$version.releasedate",
            },
        },
    }).All(&Apps); err != nil {
        ctx.Request().Context().Err()
    }

}
```

And my data is like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0d06130723220b37eabf01"),
    "name" : "MY APP",
    "description" : "This is a good app",
    "status" : 1,
    "versions" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e0d06130723220b37eabf02"),
            "releasedescription" : "Description",
            "releasedate" : "2021-01-01",
            "filelink" : "https://...",
            "status" : 1,
            "versionnumber" : "12.0.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Out put is empty! Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: try to print the `err`

Comment: Your `ApplicationVersion` has 2 fields mapped to `_id`. It looks `ApplicationID` should be mapped to `applicationid` instead.

Comment: Thanks friends, The problem is related to duplicated key in $project object, printing the error helped me.